# Jenkins Pipeline - Push, PullRequest, and Tag events

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to create a Jenkins Job which is capable of delivering all these 3 kinds of events to this sample pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
        label 'pipeline-docker-agent'
    }
}
stages {
    stage('Build Branches and PR') {
        /*Test, vet, build and discard*/
        when { anyOf{ branch "*"; changeRequest() } }
        steps {
            echo 'test,vet and build'
        }
    }
    stage('Publish master Artifact') {
        when { branch 'master' }
        steps {
            echo 'Then Push the artifact, since its the master..'
            echo 'Then Tag the SCM as required'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy to Stage') {
        when { tag "rc-*" }
        steps {
            echo 'Downloading the artifact'
            echo 'Deploying to STAGEing'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy prod') {
        when { tag "release-*" }
        steps {
            echo 'Downloading the artifact'
            echo 'Deploying to Prod'
        }
    }
}
```

How to do that, which all plugins should I install?

Coming from modern CI tools like drone.io, circleCI. Jenkins pipeline was being advertised as equivalent to these modern CI tools. Trying to replicate similar behavior in Jenkins.

Unfortunately, moving from Jenkins pipeline to one of the above-said CI tools is not an option in my current organization. Our platform/Infra architecture folks have an obsession for ancient tools and technologies. Sigh!. Rant over. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

One more specific use-case is, I want to trigger auto-build on all the new events, not on the past events. (One of the plugin that tried even triggered a build for closed PRs and ages old Tag etc)

GitHub Enterprise is the SCM.

Tried with Multi-branch Pipeline configuration

Comment: What was the issue with multibranch plugin?

Comment: problem was not with the Multi-branch Pipeline. Its with the Plugins. Couldnt simply find one plugin which will run a pipeline for all the above-said 3 kinds of events

Comment: sorry, but it's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I almost got settled on this one plugin, this fits my bill https://github.com/KostyaSha/github-integration-plugin. I will add the answer when I am done with the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Jenkins Plugin which will fit my bill

https://github.com/KostyaSha/github-integration-plugin

This plugin along with multi-branch pipeline Job configuration is letting me create a pipeline which can handle Commit, PR and Tag events

### Here is the Configuration

[image]
[image]

I had to slightly change my pipeline declarative syntax

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'pipes-docker-agent'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build Branches and PR') {
            /*Test, vet, build */
            when { expression { !env.GITHUB_TAG_NAME } }
            steps {
                echo 'test,vet and build'
            }
        }
        stage('Publish master Artifact') {
            /*Jenkins have a problem with the intuitive syntax */
            when { expression { env.BRANCH_NAME && env.BRANCH_NAME.toString().equals('master') } }
            steps {
                echo 'Then Push the above-built artifact, since its the master. Need to have similar strategy for Hotfix branches'
                echo 'Then Tag the SCM as required'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy to Stage') {
            when {expression { env.GITHUB_TAG_NAME && env.GITHUB_TAG_NAME.toString().startsWith("rc-") } }
            steps {
                echo 'Downloading the artifact'
                echo 'Deploying to STAGEing'
            }
        }
        /* I think its wise to move this as another Job*/
        stage('Deploy prod') {
            when {expression { env.GITHUB_TAG_NAME && env.GITHUB_TAG_NAME.toString().startsWith("release-") } }
            steps {
                echo 'Downloading the artifact'
                echo 'Deploying to Prod'
            }
        }
    }
}
```